# Images not created according to range defined using imagedatagenerator and flow

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I have written a code for data augmentation and to save the images only. There is no model created yet. I plan to create augmented images first only and then train my model later.The problem is that not all images are being taken into augmentation and saving. 
I have 275 images with a range of 50 which means that there should be total 13750 images created however I'm only getting about 7500 images from the augmentation. I tried to debug and found out that there is no problem in reading of the image as well as augmenting it but rather the. Follow method does not save the images. It gets worse when the `save_format` argument is chosen as jpeg. I wish to know why this happening and more importantly if there is a solution to this or getting around this problem.(Note:-Im only a beginner in this domain).

```
import cv2
import glob
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


types=('*.png','*.jpg','*.jpeg','*.jfif','*.bmp')
path2="C:\\Users\\Cato\\Desktop\\BE project\\Augmented data\\hugging"
#path2="C:\\Users\\Cato\\Desktop\\output"
datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40,width_shift_range=0.27,height_shift_range=0.27,zoom_range=[0.9,1.5],brightness_range=[0.3,1.0],horizontal_flip=True,vertical_flip=False)
i=0;
for files in types:
    path1="C:\\Users\\Cato\\Desktop\\BE project\\Augmented data\\grayscale\\hugging\\"+str(files)
    #path1="C:\\Users\\Cato\\Desktop\\input\\"+str(files)
    i=i+1;
    for file in glob.glob(path1):
        i=i+1;
        image = np.expand_dims(cv2.imread(file), 0)
        datagen.fit(image)
        for x,val in zip(datagen.flow(image,save_to_dir=path2),range(50)):
            pass


print("Augmentation completed")
```

Comment: I think you want to use `flow_from_directory`, no? By the way, you don't need to save the augmentations. You should use them directly on `model.fit_generator(datagen.flow_from_directory(...), ...)`

Comment: I tried with flow_from_directory technique still shows the same problem infact it generates even lesser images.Also i know we can use augmentation at run time but i wanted the images first seperately.

Comment: I have solved the issue. You were right about using flow_from_directory.Thank you so much!

Comment: How do i close the question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems because of which this issue was arising. First was to use flow_from_directory and second I dont know why but saving the image in jpeg format solved the issue. I am guessing the saving mechanism behind the code doesnt quite work for png format  for unknown reasons. Although it should be noted it solved the problem considerably but not all the way. Meaning if i wanted 15000 images to be generated from  the datagenerator it now produces 13500 images. If the image was saved in png format this count of image would reduce to 7-8k images.